# Kerberos authentication in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, kerberos

I want to use Kerberos authentication with groovy. I have a simple java program that works for me, here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class RunHttpSpnego {

    static final String kuser = "host/myaccount"; 
    static final String kpass = "password"; 

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
        URL url = new URL("http://myhost/wsapi/subscriptions");

        InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String str;
        while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

plus a configuration file like this:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule 
        required useTicketCache=true;
};
```

and run it like this:

```
java -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/pathtoconf/spnegoLogin.conf RunHttpSpnego
```

So I wrote something similar in groovy, but it doesn't work.

The code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

def kuser = "username"; 
def kpass = "password"; 

dd = new DataDict();
dd.init();

public class DataDict {

static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        System.err.println("Feeding username and password for "
           + getRequestingScheme());
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
    }
}

void init(String propertyPath, List options){

Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

URL url = new URL("http://myhost/wsapi/subscriptions");

InputStream ins = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
String str;
while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
System.out.println(str);

}
}
```

and I run it like this:

```
groovy -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/pathtoconf/spnegoLogin.conf PopulateDataDict.gy
```

I also tried putting it in JAVA_OPTS, but I still get 401. I checked, getPasswordAuthentication() gets called in groovy, but it doesn't look like it works.

Why java code works and groovy doesn't and what do I need to change to make it work?

EDIT: Ok, it's my stupid error, need to make user/password static variables.

Comment: You should be able use java code as is in groovy. Have you tried like that?

Comment: java program run as groovy works. So I wonder what's the difference?

Comment: Not sure if that can fit into comment. Never the less, you should be able to find in the net if you looking for answers only for that.